# Free software to combine audios and images into a video

Tags: open-source, video, images, video-editing

Is there any free software to combine audios and images into a video?

I already tried looking and tried Lightworks and other alike softwares but they seem to require too much work.

I am looking for something simple, press of a button and it will join audio and images into video, no question asked.

Comment: For which operating system? What else (besides Lightworks) did you try?

Answer (score 1):

[**OpenShot**](https://www.openshot.org/) is a simple open source video editor with support for Windows, Linux and Mac. Basic use cases include putting an image/video track and an audio track and make them play at the same time.

[**Shotcut**](https://shotcut.org/) is also a nice video editor that received a 4.5/5 stars review form [TechRadar](https://www.techradar.com/reviews/shotcut).

Other open source alternatives that are not as minimal and simple as these two may include  [**Avidemux**](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/), [**Hitfilm**](https://fxhome.com/hitfilm-express) and [**Movavi**](https://www.movavi.com/videoeditor/).

**Windows Movie Maker** is not open source but with it you can easily do the same. Development and official downloads have been discontinued, but the same features are offered in [**Microsoft Photos**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-photos/9wzdncrfjbh4?activetab=pivot:overviewtab). Not open source either but Microsoft is progressively open sourcing its essential Windows app, like [Calculator](https://github.com/Microsoft/calculator).